# Angularjs filter overriding after onload

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have defualt currency filter on my page, using angularjs syntax

```
{{ '200' | currency:"USD$" }}
```

After my page's load, I would like to override the currency code by a click action. **How can I do that?**

#### On page load

```
$200
```

#### After javascript call

```
€200
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use filter in binding but in controller:

```
myModule.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", "currencyFilter", function($scope, currencyFilter) {
    $scope.myValue = 200;
    $scope.myCurrency = currencyFilter($scope.myValue, "USD$");
    $scope.updateToEuro = fucntion() {
        $scope.myCurrency = currencyFilter($scope.myValue, "EURO€");
    }
}
```

Then your binding become:

```
<span ng-click="updateToEuro()">{{ myCurrency }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
myModule.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.Value = 200;

    $scope.currencyType = "$";

    $scope.changeCurrencyType = function(){
     $scope.currencyType = "€";
    }

}
```

and html code like this

```
<button type="button" ng-click="changeCurrencyType()">Change Language</button>

<div>{{Value}}{{currencyType}}</div>
```

hope this works for you.